# Расположения col-lg-* при маленьком размере

Tags: css, bootstrap, разметка

Здравствуйте, вот пример: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0k2ou5w/1/embedded/result/)

При уменьшение экрана видно, что блоки располагаются друг под другом. Можно ли сделать так, что бы при сворачивании, блок с авторизацией был с верху, а в развёрнутом виде он был с право(как сейчас)? Вот код с примера:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="test">Любой <b>DIV</b> блок</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">Авторизация</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Логин">
                  <br>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Пароль">
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменять порядок можно используя классы `.col-*-push-*` и `.col-*-pull-*`.
В вашем примере я изменил порядок блоков на маленьких экранах, чтоб на маленьких сразу все отображалось правильно, и добавил классы перетягивания блоков на больших экранах

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">Авторизация</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Логин">
          <br>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Пароль">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="test">Любой <b>DIV</b> блок</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2dnsj2jz/2/

Документация Bootstrap о порядке блоков http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering